# Hadoop mapreduce has "Cannot resolve the host name" error

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Now I run Hadoop mapreduce job, the input data comes from HBase table, recently there is an error, the error is below:

**ERROR mapreduce.TableInputFormatBase: Cannot resolve the host name for /172.16.4.195 because of javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: DNS name not found [response code 3]; remaining name '195.4.16.172.in-addr.arpa'**

**172.16.4.195**is cluster node(slave)ip adress, I do not know what is "195.4.16.172".

There was no such error when I firstly run this job,I do not know why there is such an error.
If you solved the problem,please tell me,thank you.

Answer (score 2):

reverse dns not found, you need add something like

```
172.16.4.195 master_host_name
```

to hosts file

if running on linux, the file located at /etc/hosts

if running on windows, the file located at %WINDIR%/System32/Drivers/etc/hosts

Comment: I also have the same issue and my /etc/hosts files contains the proper entries. The map/reduce job appears to be working but runs on my local machine. Cloudera also doesn't recognize that a map/reduce job task is running.

Comment: what is `master_host_name` in the mentioned answer